# Combine different case rules in one Perl regular expression

Tags: regex, perl

I have a Perl variable, `$word`. I want to do a regex like this:

```
$text =~ /ab($word)cd/;
```

I want the regex to be case-sensitive for the `ab` and `cd` parts, but *not* for whatever is in `$word`. So if `$word='stack'`, I would want both of these to match:

```
abstackcd
abStAcKcd
```

etc., but I don't want to match

```
Abstackcd
```

I guess I'm looking for some way to apply the `/i` just to `$word` but not the rest of the expression. Can this be done?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, using `(?i:$word)`. See the section ["Extended Patterns" of perldoc perlre](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/perlre#Extended_Patterns). You may have actually wanted `(?i:\Q$word\E)`, by the way, which will automatically quote any regex metacharacters that are in `$word`.